# Javascript. Writing data from asynchronous function

Tags: javascript

For my project, I am waiting and downloading data from Google Spreadsheet. My problem is that the LoadData function plays every time the user clicks on dropdown, because of this the LoadData function loads the same data from google tables again and the huge problem is that I can't use this data anywhere else but the LoadData function which makes it huge and does other unnecessary things that could be done once. The solution is to unload the variable data into the global scope or at least load the data there from the LoadData function, but this is impossible because I need an Asynchronous function. What should I do?

Here is the code:

```
async function fetchData(){
    const dataResponse = await fetch(urls);
    const data = await dataResponse.json();
    return data;
}

async function LoadData(selectedData = 0, loadThing = false)
{
    let data = await fetchData();
    if(loadThing)
    {
        //Load date to the DropDown
        for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            MakeCoolDropdown(data.values[dataEnum.Date][i], i);  
    }

    let keys = Object.keys(dataEnum);
    for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //Put Values from data to HTML page
        let key = keys[i];
        PutInHtml(key, data.values[dataEnum[key]][selectedData]);
    }
}

let btn = document.getElementById("dropdown2_The_Movie");

btn.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    let dropdownID      = document.getElementById("dropdown2_The_Movie");
    let dropdownValue   = dropdownID.selectedIndex;
    LoadData(dropdownValue);
});
```

Comment: "*loads the same data from google tables again*" - you can cache the data in a global scope variable. But no, all the things that you want to do with the loaded data must be done (triggered) from within the `loadData` function, there's no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the resource once, store in a variable in the scope of the script, or elsewhere

```
let data = void 0;

async function fetchData(){
    const dataResponse = await fetch(urls);
    const data = await dataResponse.json();
    return data;
}

async function LoadData(selectedData = 0, loadThing = false) {
  // Load data exactly once from the network
  if (data === undefined) {
    data = await fetchData();
  }
  // ...
}
```